# Items Similarity based on their features

Tags: similarity, recommendation-engine, mahout-recommender

I have a dataset with items but with no user ratings. 
Items have features (~400 feature).
I want to measure the similarity between items based on features (Row similarity).

I convert the item-feature into a binary matrix like the fowllowing

`itemID | feature1 | feature2 | feature3 | feature4 ....
  1     |    0     |    1     |    1     |    0 
  2     |    1     |    0     |    0     |    1
  3     |    1     |    1     |    1     |    0
  4     |    0     |    0     |    1     |    1`


 I don't know what to use (and how to use it) to measure the row similarity.

 
 I want, for Item X, to get the top k similar items.

A sample code will be very appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is termed *similarity measure*. A quick google/SO search will reveal various methods to get similarity between two vectors. Here is some sample code in python2 for cosine similarity:

```
from math import *

def square_rooted(x):
    return round(sqrt(sum([a*a for a in x])),3)

def cosine_similarity(x,y):
    numerator = sum(a*b for a,b in zip(x,y))
    denominator = square_rooted(x)*square_rooted(y)
    return round(numerator/float(denominator),3)

print cosine_similarity([3, 45, 7, 2], [2, 54, 13, 15])
```

taken from: http://dataaspirant.com/2015/04/11/five-most-popular-similarity-measures-implementation-in-python/

I noticed that you want top k similar items for every item. The best way to do that is with a k Nearest Neighbour implementation. What you can do is create a knn graph and return the top k similar items from the graph for a query.

A great library for this is [`nmslib`](https://github.com/searchivarius/nmslib). Here is some sample code for a knn query [from the library](https://github.com/searchivarius/nmslib/tree/master/python_bindings) for the HNSW method with cosine similarity (you can use one of the several available methods. HNSW is particularly efficient for your high dimensional data):

```
import nmslib
import numpy

# create a random matrix to index
data = numpy.random.randn(10000, 100).astype(numpy.float32)

# initialize a new index, using a HNSW index on Cosine Similarity
index = nmslib.init(method='hnsw', space='cosinesimil')
index.addDataPointBatch(data)
index.createIndex({'post': 2}, print_progress=True)

# query for the nearest neighbours of the first datapoint
ids, distances = index.knnQuery(data[0], k=10)

# get all nearest neighbours for all the datapoint
# using a pool of 4 threads to compute
neighbours = index.knnQueryBatch(data, k=10, num_threads=4)
```

At the end of the code, the k top neighbours for every data point will be stored in the `neighbours` variable. You can use that for your purposes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,

Comment: just want to know where did you get these numbers ([3, 45, 7, 2], [2, 54, 13, 15]) ??

Comment: They are just sample data. Put in your data vectors to get the similarity between any two vectors. Also, try navigating to the links I added. They contain a lot of relevant information